# xml parsing in iOS swift

Tags: ios, xml, swift, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I am having bar or QR code scanning of Aadhar card.I am getting the response as the following xml format.How to convert this into dictionary format using xml parsing?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><PrintLetterBarcodeData uid="685860050795" name="Sangeetha D" gender="F" yob="1989" co="W/O: Dhanansekaran" house="632" street="saradhambal nagar" lm="agaramel" vtc="Nazarathpettai" po="Nazarethpettai" dist="Tiruvallur" subdist="Poonamallee" state="Tamil Nadu" pc="600123" dob="03/06/1989"/>
```

I tried the following code for parsing

```
 public func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    currentElement=elementName;

    print(currentElement)


}

public func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    currentElement="";

}

public func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {

}
```

But its returning always the `currentElement` as "PrintLetterBarcodeData"

Comment: @Wain I edited my question

Comment: I do not think that you have to write your own methods to handle it because you'd rather want to work with the data you receive. You can use one of the libraries listed [here](https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#xml--html) if you are ok with using third party libraries.

Comment: Your XML has only one level. It's normal. But you may be interested in `attributeDict`.

Comment: are you able to decode the secure aadhar QR? in ios?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's some parsing code I wrote in Swift 3 based off of a [Google News RSS reader](https://github.com/JALsnipe/google-news-reader) I previously wrote in Swift 2.0.  I have this code modified to handle a list of `PrintLetterBarcodeData` elements as well as a single one:

```
class BarcodeData {
    var uid: String
    var name: String
    var gender: String
    var yob: String
    var co: String
    var house: String
    var street: String
    var lm: String
    var vtc: String
    var po: String
    var dist: String
    var subdist: String
    var state: String
    var pc: String
    var dob: String

    init?(dictionary: [String : String]) {
        guard let uid = dictionary["uid"],
            let name = dictionary["name"],
            let gender = dictionary["gender"],
            let yob = dictionary["yob"],
            let co = dictionary["co"],
            let house = dictionary["house"],
            let street = dictionary["street"],
            let lm = dictionary["lm"],
            let vtc = dictionary["vtc"],
            let po = dictionary["po"],
            let dist = dictionary["dist"],
            let subdist = dictionary["subdist"],
            let state = dictionary["state"],
            let pc = dictionary["pc"],
            let dob = dictionary["dob"] else {
            return nil
        }

        self.uid = uid
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
        self.yob = yob
        self.co = co
        self.house = house
        self.street = street
        self.lm = lm
        self.vtc = vtc
        self.po = po
        self.dist = dist
        self.subdist = subdist
        self.state = state
        self.pc = pc
        self.dob = dob

    }
}

class MyParser: NSObject {
    var parser: XMLParser

    var barcodes = [BarcodeData]()

    init(xml: String) {
        parser = XMLParser(data: xml.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        super.init()
        parser.delegate = self
    }

    func parseXML() -> [BarcodeData] {
        parser.parse()
        return barcodes
    }

}

extension MyParser: XMLParserDelegate {

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

        if elementName == "PrintLetterBarcodeData" {

            if let barcode = BarcodeData(dictionary: attributeDict) {
                barcodes.append(barcode)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><PrintLetterBarcodeData uid=\"685860050795\" name=\"Sangeetha D\" gender=\"F\" yob=\"1989\" co=\"W/O: Dhanansekaran\" house=\"632\" street=\"saradhambal nagar\" lm=\"agaramel\" vtc=\"Nazarathpettai\" po=\"Nazarethpettai\" dist=\"Tiruvallur\" subdist=\"Poonamallee\" state=\"Tamil Nadu\" pc=\"600123\" dob=\"03/06/1989\"/>"

let parser = MyParser(xml: xmlString)
let barcodes = parser.parseXML() // array of barcodes
barcodes.first // your barcode
```

Comment: Its good you have provided a way for parsing aadhar data.. but you must know that aadhar data is private information of a user. So kindly ensure not to present private data of user on public websites.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though your expected XML structure only consists of the root element `PrintLetterBarcodeData` and its attributes.

You will find the attributes of your root element in the `attributeDict` property in the `didStartElement` delegate method.

For example, to extract the `name` property, you would do:

```
public func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    currentElement=elementName;
    print(currentElement)
    //print name
    if let name = attributeDict["name"] {
        print(name) //prints Sangeetha D
    }
}
```